# Azure Managed Database Instance - Can't modify stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, instance

All, our company uses Azure Managed Database Instance and they work fine, except when I try to right-click a procedure and select modify, it produces an error message: **Invalid version: 16. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo).**

This happens to any stored procedure I try to modify. It also happens if I right-click a procedure and try to script it ... But, if I connect to this db server from an on-premise sql server instance, I can modify or script the procedure without any problem. This appears to be an issue with Azure Managed Instance.

I checked the permissions on the user, tried connecting from on-premise sql server, searched for online help. I haven't found any answers to this question.

Comment: Try updating your SQL Server Management Studio version perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Invalid version: 15 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262748/sql-server-invalid-version-15-microsoft-sqlserver-smo)

Answer (score 1):

As @Thom A notes, you probably just need to update SSMS, but alternatively, here's how to modify a stored procedure without SMO/SSMS scripting it for you.

You can use [OBJECT_DEFINITION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the stored procedure DDL, and then print it to the console.  Then copy and modify it (change CEREATE to CREATE OR ALTER). eg

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (
select OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id('dbo.uspGetBillOfMaterials')) d)

SELECT @sql AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

The PRINT command truncates long strings, so this trick of using xml allows long strings to be sent to the client without character escaping.

Comment: CREATE OR _ALTER_. :-)

Comment: Too much Spark SQL lately...